# How can I select some items in Bootstrap-select when page initiates?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap select (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/.) for multiple selection of items. I would like to know how can I select some items when pageloads.

Comment: What is your HTML code?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', ['Ketchup','Relish']);
```

Will work for this select:

```
<div class="container">
 <select class="selectpicker" multiple>
     <option>Mustard</option>
     <option>Ketchup</option>
     <option>Relish</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**http://www.bootply.com/64070**